# How to apply filter and show/hide columns in React Table - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am working on React Table. I am basically a beginner in React. I have a dashboard page where I display a React Table of 8 columns. I have a customize button which will open a popup page, this popup page has 8 check boxes allows me to show/hide those React columns. Initially all the check boxes in this popup page is set to true. When I uncheck a column that particular column get disabled.

The first image only has columns (no sub columns are there but in real life I will have to use sub columns) . Also in the 1st image there are 8 check boxes. It is 10 in real life. The 2nd image basically shows the basic columns. I am basically telling you as this images do not 100% correlate to my functionality. It shows a basic idea

[image: Image which basically shows the checkboxes, the column names are updated now]

[image: Image which basically shows the 8 columns and their sub columns]

This is my column data (total 8 columns, column 1 to 5 and column 7 has one sub column while column 6 & column 8 has multiple sub columns)

I need to apply show/hide filter on the level 1 header (super header) and level 2 headers of column 1 to 5. Column 6 to 8 are always visible.

It is to be noted that I have a constant file in my project. Whenever I use the global constants of that file in other components I import it.

It should be mentioned that React Table has a property called show (default value is true but we can hide a column by setting it false)

```
const Constants = {
  columnShowHide: [
    { id: 1, value: true },
    { id: 2, value: true },
    { id: 3, value: true },
    { id: 4, value: true },
    { id: 5, value: true },
    { id: 6, value: true },
    { id: 7, value: true },
    { id: 8, value: true },
    { id: 9, value: true },
    { id: 10, value: true },
  ]
};

export { Constants as default };
```

This is the code for the popup page for checkbox

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../../../actions';
import ButtonComponent from '../../common/button/ButtonComponent';
import { CheckBox } from '../../common/chkbox/CheckBox';
import Constants from '../../../util/constants';

class CustomizedView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCheckChildElement = this.handleCheckChildElement.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Sub Column 1', isChecked: true },
        { id: 2, value: 'Super Column 1', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, value: 'Sub Column 2', isChecked: true },
        { id: 4, value: 'Super Column 2', isChecked: true },
        { id: 5, value: 'Column 5', isChecked: true },
        { id: 6, value: 'Column 6', isChecked: true },
        { id: 7, value: 'Column 7', isChecked: true },
        { id: 8, value: 'Column 8', isChecked: true },
        { id: 9, value: 'Column 7', isChecked: true },
        { id: 10, value: 'Column 8', isChecked: true },
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked });
  }

  handleCheckChildElement(event) {
    const { items } = this.state; //extract state values like this to a const variable
    const newItems = items.map((item) => { //do map on items because map returns a new array. It’s good practice to use .map than forEach in your case
      if(item.value === event.target.value) {
        item.isChecked = event.target.checked;
        return item; //return updated item object so that it will be pushed to the newItems array
      }
      return item; // return item because you need this item object as well
    });
    this.setState({ items: newItems }); //finally set newItems array into items


Constants.columnShowHide[0].value = items[0].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[1].value = items[1].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[2].value = items[2].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[3].value = items[3].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[4].value = items[4].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[5].value = items[5].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[6].value = items[6].isChecked;
Constants.columnShowHide[7].value = items[7].isChecked;
console.log('From constant file after ' + JSON.stringify(Constants.columnShowHide));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='div-container-custom' >
        <div className='bottomBar'>
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Apply'
            className='activeButton filterMargin-custom'
            width='100'
            display='inline-block'
            onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(this.state, false); }}
          />
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Clear Filter'
            className='greyedButton clear-custom-filter'
            width='100'
            display='block'
            marginTop='60'
            onClick={() => { this.props.clearFilter(this.state, true); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className='data-points-text'>
            <span> Columns </span>
          </div>
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                  return (<div key={i} ><CheckBox handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement} {...item} /></div>);
                })
              };
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CustomizedView.propTypes = {
  applyFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

CustomizedView.defaultProps = {
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedView);
```

Now I need to use the constant to moduify my ReactTableComponent

This is my column data in React Table component

```
const columns = [
 {
    Header: 'Column 1',
        columns: [
           {
               Header: 'S Column 1',
               accessor: 'firstName',
               show : some_var (if this is true,column/sub column in shown, else hidden )
           }
      ]
  },
  {
      Header: 'Column 2',
       columns: [
         {
            Header: 'S Column 2',
            accessor: 'firstName'
          }
       ]
     },
    {
            Header: 'Column 3',
            columns: [
    {
            Header: 'S Column 3',
            accessor: 'firstName'
          }
         ]
   },
    {
          Header: 'Column 4',
          columns: [
    {
            Header: 'S column 4',
            accessor: 'firstName'
     }
    ]
      },
     {
     Header: 'Column 5',
    columns: [
    {
    Header: 'S column 5',
     accessor: 'firstName'
    }
   ]
   },
  {
     Header: 'Column 6',
     columns: [
  {
        Header: 'S column 6a',
        accessor: 'firstName'
  },
   {
        Header: 'S column 6b',
        accessor: 'firstName'
    },
    {
        Header: 'S column 6c',
        accessor: 'firstName'
     },
    {
         Header: 'S column 6d',
         accessor: 'firstName'
    }
  ]
     },
      {
     Header: 'Column 7',
     columns: [
     {
      Header: 'S column 7',
         accessor: 'firstName'
   }
    ]
     },
      {
        Header: 'Column 8',
        columns: [
      {
       Header: 'S Column 8a',
       accessor: 'firstName'
      },
     {
       Header: 'S Column 8b',
       accessor: 'firstName'
     },
    {
    Header: 'S Column 8c',
    accessor: 'firstName'
    },
    {
      Header: 'S Column 8d',
      accessor: 'firstName'
      }
     ]
      },
      ];
```

Now I have the 10 boolean flags in Constants.js  which I can import in any component. It is available across the project. I have checked by consoling.

Initially all the flags are true so when the checkbox popup page opens, so when I uncheck and press apply button that particular columns/sub columns will be hidden.

The checkbox values can be brought to initial state by clearFilters function. All columns and sub columns should show after clearFilter

Now since I am complete beginner In React, what should I write in the function of Apply and clear button to implement my desired idea. I have some incorrect functions. Also after pressing applyFilter/clearFilter I need to update the global constants and use them in ReactTableComponent to use the show property of ReactTable to show/hide columns/sub columns.

I am not using Redux or any complex things. I have a working constants file and I want to use that to implement this. Kindly help me in achieving this